# Alert Box display only once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have an alert box that is triggered when users mouseover a certain area.
Here is the code:

```
$("#contentfooter:contains(This website)").mouseover(function(){
 $(".navTopItemGroup_6").slideDown("slow");
  alert("You've Unlocked A Hidden Area");
  });
```

How do I prevent this alert box from activating more than one time?
i.e., When they mouseover the area once, I don't want the alert box to pop up if they mouseover it twice.

Comment: is it possible to have a counter at the beggining of the code to check for this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `one()` http://api.jquery.com/one/.

```
$element.one('mouseover', function(){ ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

The .one() method will work if you don't hide the content again.  But if you do, then simply change your mouseover event to mouseenter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rt7Ns/)

[one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) binds an event handler and the unbinds it on its first execution.